# Deploying a project on a server

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, glassfish

I developed a website using netbeans 6.9.1 and glassfish and now i have to install it on a real server. What are the steps i should take to make this working ?

> ```
> 1.) Install the exact version of MySQL i was working on my machine
> 2.) Install Glass fish (I think i did something after logging into
> ```
>
> Glassfish admin portal, but i am not sure what i did)

Can someone brief me up with what i have to do ?

Comment: Is this for commercial usage or for college/homework? If it is the former, get some professional help; maybe from the folks hosting the servers. We might be able to help you, but there are way too many things to put down in an answer.

Comment: Not for commercial use. Its academic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must take care of several things:

1. correct / supported OS (MySQL, Glassfish, JDK) and hosting environment (physical, virtual, cloud, etc.)
2. JDK version / vendor
3. storage requirements
4. Glassfish installation, installation guide is [here](http://glassfish.java.net/docs/index.html)
5. MySQL installation, if I remember correctly it's packaged with the product
6. Configure all components for production (e.g. JVM heap size, OS configuration)
7. If required set up appropriate monitoring tools (servers up, storage allocations, etc.)
8. Verify whether you can get a least 2 (e.g. virtual) servers (production, staging/test)

You should create proper installation guides and operational manuals, this depends on your environment. This can become a complex task...

Edit: Depending on your non-functional requirements you may want to have the DB on a separate server and build an application server cluster. As @Vineet mentioned you should look for professional help if it's a large environment.

Comment: `Verify whether you can get a least 2 (e.g. virtual) servers (production, staging/test)` i didn't understand this part

Comment: @Illep: If possible get a test server :-)

Comment: OK.. so where should i copy the jar and the `xhtml` pages to ?

Comment: @Illep: don't understand your question... in general you deploy EARs or WARs on glassfish